ActivityMissingException using Geolocator's requestPermission() even with WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()
I'm getting an ActivityMissingException when requesting location permissions using the Geolocator plugin in Flutter:
ActivityMissingException (Activity is missing. This might happen when running a certain function from the background that requires a UI element (e.g. requesting permissions or enabling the location services).)

The error occurs on this line:
permission = await _geolocatorPlatform.requestPermission();
Where final GeolocatorPlatform _geolocatorPlatform = GeolocatorPlatform.instance;
I've tried:

Using WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback (shown below)
Adding Future.delayed with various delays (up to 10 seconds, everything was definitely loaded)
Checking context.mounted before requests (shown below)
Moving the permission request to the first build using Future.microtask

My current implementation for my initState function in my Home page widget:
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (mounted) {
      handleLocationPermission(context);
    }
  });
}

My current implementation for my handleLocationPermission function:
Future<void> handleLocationPermission(BuildContext context) async {
  if (!context.mounted) return;

  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;
  LocationAccuracyStatus accuracy;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await _geolocatorPlatform.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the
    // App to enable the location services.
    if (!context.mounted) return;
    showAlert(context,
        title: locationDisabledAlertTitle,
        text1: locationDisabledAlertText1,
        text2: locationDisabledAlertText2,
        doNothingActionText: "Ok",
        doSomethingActionText: "Open Settings", onDoSomething: () {
      _geolocatorPlatform.openLocationSettings();
    });
    return;
  }

  // Test if permissions are given. If not, request permission.
  permission = await _geolocatorPlatform.checkPermission();
  if (!context.mounted) return; // Added these extra mount checks
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await _geolocatorPlatform.requestPermission(); // Fails here
  }
  ...

Flutter doctor (no issues found):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 15.1 24B83 darwin-arm64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.95.1)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] Network resources

Environment:

Geolocator plugin version: 12.0.0
Platform: Pixel 6 Android 14 (API 34)

How can I properly request location permissions without getting the ActivityMissingException?
